# Android Wear: custom apperance for notification

Tags: wear-os

How to implement such appearance for notification card using Android Wear SDK?

[image: Weather Notification]

Demo video — http://youtu.be/tKoQatxG0_8?t=26s

It has the same custom layout in preview and active mode. But I cannot achieve such behaviour using setDisplayIntent and related API for creating custom layouts. I checked samples of wear apps from SDK, it also has different views for preview and active mode of custom layout notifications.

Comment: Don't understand why someone dislike the question. Is it violate any rules of stackoverflow?

Comment: It is possible right now. Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28603086/custom-ui-for-android-wear-notifications

Answer (score 0):

Oh no!

Right now it's hidden API, so Google can make such appearance for standard apps, but other third-party developers are out of the board.

Confirmed by +Wayne Piekarski — https://plus.google.com/u/0/+BenoitBoDLubek/posts/2o4SVBhWg5z

So the answer is **impossible at current moment**.